# Python 3.8 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: python

I have just upgaded from 3.7 to 3.8.

My Script worked perfectly fine, until I have upgraded to 3.8.

I have this line of code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab
```

And returns me error of this:

```
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

uninstall `Pillow` re-installed it again..

Comment: Did you re-install Pillow for Python3.8?

Comment: i already did have Pillow, uninstalled it and re-installed it again, comes with same error

Comment: which os you have used ?

Comment: How many versions of python do you have in your system?

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami just 3.7 and 3.8

Comment: @AmitPatel how do I found that out?

Comment: Do you somehow have both PIL and Pillow installed?

Comment: you used windows , ubuntu or mac?

Comment: Windows i have used

Comment: @HenryYik I have python37 folder in `users//appdata/local.programs` also in `C: program filed (x86) pyton 38`, that maybe why?

Comment: try to  ```import Image``` many time PIL does not work if  this work for you then install pillow successfully

Comment: I encountered the same error on Windows after upgrading to Python 3.8 — and had to do the same thing to fix it. Suspect it's because the difference between 3.7 and 3.8 resulted in significant changes to the interpreter's internals.

Comment: @AmitPatel `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'`

Comment: Anyway, what exactly is your question?

Comment: if you use ubuntu then try to install ```pip3 install Pillow``` because ubuntu default provide python2

Comment: I am using Windows 10, downloaded Python 3.8 from 3.7.. my PIL module is not working.. @martineau

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 and from the command-line used `pip3 uninstall Pillow` followed by `pip3 install Pillow`. Did the uninstall first because `pip3 list` indicated that it was already installed (although `from PIL import Image` didn't work). Besides fix the problem, this had the beneficial side-effect of upgrading me to the latest version of the module.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to install from the [wheel](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/5a/ee223b0503ebba3d6adcf24516cbae85d581058f2bac635fc82e4bd6c2bf/Pillow-6.2.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl)

`pip install Pillow-6.2.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

Note : This wheel is for windows 64 bits and cpython 3.8 if you want to install manually for a different system, you have to use another one.

Comment: `ERROR: Pillow-6.2.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: Well, one of the requirement is not satisfied, either windows version or cpython 3,8

Comment: Pasted the wheel in in Python/Scripts/ and ran the command there, worked like a charm!