# I keep getting this error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' although I have installed pillow from the command prompt

Tags: python, tkinter, cmd, pip, python-imaging-library

I have installed pillow through my cmd successfully but I still can't import `PIL` for some reason on Pycharm:

```
from PIL import Image
```

And get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Comment: which python version are u using?

Comment: I'm using the 3.8.5 version @UmairMubeen

Comment: Need to ask: Did you imported PIL ?

Comment: Yes, I did, from PIL import Image

Comment: on pycharm u have to install it from inside the IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pycharm uses a virtualenv for pycharm projects. Navigate through:

Pycharm >> File >> Settings(or press Ctrl+Alt+S on win) >> Project:Name >> Project Interpreter >> Click on the plus(+) symbol above the scroll bar and type in PIL and press install package.

And this vl install PIL for your Pycharm IDE. Since pycharm uses a virtual env for its projects you can change it in the project interpreter section as well, and then the PIL you installed from the cmd will be available to be used.

If u still have errors, let me know :D

Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciate your effort to help me!

Comment: Welcome to SO, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

if your `python version` is `3.8` then try this

```
pip3.8 install pil
```

Comment: I think i can't install it because I have already installed pillow, should I uninstall it and install it back?

Comment: please post the error

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: did u install pillow?

Comment: Yes, I installed it.

Comment: please uninstall it and reinstall it

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled it, but it doesn't work yet.

Comment: from cmd use this command python -m pip3.8 install pillow

Comment: doesn't help. I think the problem is not in the installation.

Comment: @kim how installed you PIL with the pip command?

Comment: @Atlas435 I used pip install pillow.

Comment: I'm a little bit clueless. Did you restart your system ?

Comment: yes, I restarted.

Comment: @kim are you on os, windows or linux?

Comment: I'm on windows.

Comment: I found this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58499343/13629335